# How to ping someone on discord with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

well basically, whenever I try and run this code

```
type = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("css-selector")
type.send_keys("@Binary#2446")
type.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

the code runs fine if I don't try and ping someone but whenever I do try and ping someone it raises an exception, **"selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"** and I know for a fact that the exception occurs on the third line, I don't see anything wrong with code. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a webhook using the import dhooks module
then just type the following code

```
from dhooks import Webhook
hook = Webhook("webhook link here")
hook.send("@Binary#2446")
```

this will only work if you have webhooks permission though and a tip when you get the webhook link remove app from it so make it discord.com not discordapp.com

Answer (score 0):

**So You Just wanna Ping someone on Discord using selenium?**

Here is my code make sure you add the credentials:

Please let me know if this works for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
time.sleep(6)

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
username_input.send_keys("enter-your-username-here")


password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_input.send_keys("Enter-your-password-here")


login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
login_button.click()

driver.get("Enter the channel URL where you wanna send the message")
print(">Opening The Server Link...")
time.sleep(5)

while(i <= 100):
        time.sleep(30)
        msg_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/form/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div')
        msg_input.send_keys("@an7yone")
        msg_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        i+=1
        print(">Number of Messages sent: "+str(i))
    print("Its Done!")
```